# How to run multiple cucumberjs tags

Tags: cucumberjs

I'm using grunt tasks to run my feature files using grunt cucumberjs

```
grunt cucumberjs --cucumbertags=@favourite
```

Above command runs all the scenarios with @favourite tag. I have an issue where i want scenarios to run on different env with diff data that belongs to environment.

```
@Book
Scenario Outline: Search by Author
    When I search for "Leo Tolstoy"
    Then I should see "<number_of_books>" books

@qa_env
Examples:
| number_of_books |
| 5               |

@dev_env
Examples:
| number_of_books |
| 3               |
```

How can I run scenario @Book with @qa_env data and @Book with @dev_env data ?

Comment: Which version of CucumberJS are you using?

Comment: Hi, it is grunt-cucumber@3.0 and cucumber@0.4.9

Answer (score 1):

From the [readme of `grunt-cucumber`](https://github.com/s9tpepper/grunt-cucumber-js)

========================================================================

**tags**

Type: *String* or *Array*

Default: ''

Only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching TAG_EXPRESSION. Scenarios inherit tags declared on the Feature level. The simplest TAG_EXPRESSION is simply a tag. Example: tags: '@dev'

When a tag in a tag expression starts with a ~, this represents boolean NOT. Example: tags: `~@dev`

A tag expression can have several tags separated by a comma, which represents logical OR. Example: tags: `@dev,@wip`

To represent a logical AND, use an array. This is useful if you want to skip certain features and run other specific features. Example: tags: `['~@wip', '@dev']`

========================================================================

When you are on Windows you need to mind the usage of single and double quotes